# How to improve quality of signature image embedded in pdf

Tags: java, image, pdf, image-processing, itext

I am working on an web application to embed signature to pdf document. I am using following library [Zetakey Sign & Send](https://github.com/jackccwong/signsend).From the signature pad signature is captured using:

```
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png",1);
```

And in the server side(first Base64 decoding of signature string):

```
    public String createSignature(String mySignature,int width,int height) throws IOException {
    String filePath = SIGNATURE_PATH +"signature_" + new Date().getTime() + ".png";
    byte[] imageByteArray = decodeImage(mySignature);
    try(FileOutputStream imageOutFile = new FileOutputStream(filePath)){
        imageOutFile.write(imageByteArray);
    }
    try {
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));
        image = scaleImage(image, width, height);
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(filePath));
        for(Iterator<ImageWriter> iw = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png"); iw.hasNext();) {
            ImageWriter writer = iw.next();
            ImageWriteParam writeParam = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
            ImageTypeSpecifier typeSpecifier = ImageTypeSpecifier.createFromBufferedImageType(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
            IIOMetadata metadata = writer.getDefaultImageMetadata(typeSpecifier, writeParam);
            if(metadata.isReadOnly() || !metadata.isStandardMetadataFormatSupported()) {
                continue;
            }
            setDPI(metadata,500,width,height);
            try (ImageOutputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath))){
                writer.setOutput(stream);
                writer.write(metadata, new IIOImage(image, null, metadata), writeParam);
            }
            break;

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
          logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }

    return filePath;
}

private static void setDPI(IIOMetadata metadata, int value, int width, int height) throws IIOInvalidTreeException {
    double dotsPerMilli = value/(INCH_TO_CM*10);

    IIOMetadataNode horiz = new IIOMetadataNode("HorizontalPixelSize");
    horiz.setAttribute(VAL, Double.toString(dotsPerMilli));
    IIOMetadataNode vert = new IIOMetadataNode("VerticalPixelSize");
    vert.setAttribute(VAL, Double.toString(dotsPerMilli));

    IIOMetadataNode horizScreenSize = new IIOMetadataNode("HorizontalScreenSize");
    horizScreenSize.setAttribute(VAL, Integer.toString(width));

    IIOMetadataNode vertScreenSize = new IIOMetadataNode("VerticalScreenSize");
    vertScreenSize.setAttribute(VAL, Integer.toString(height));

    IIOMetadataNode dim = new IIOMetadataNode("Dimension");
    dim.appendChild(horiz);
    dim.appendChild(vert);
    dim.appendChild(horizScreenSize);
    dim.appendChild(vertScreenSize);

    IIOMetadataNode root = new IIOMetadataNode("javax_imageio_1.0");
    root.appendChild(dim);

    metadata.mergeTree("javax_imageio_1.0", root);
}

public static BufferedImage scaleImage(BufferedImage original, int width, int height){
    BufferedImage scaled = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale(((float)width)/original.getWidth(), ((float)height)/original.getHeight());
    Map<RenderingHints.Key, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
    map.put(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
    map.put(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(map);
    AffineTransformOp scaleOp = new AffineTransformOp(at, hints);
    scaled = scaleOp.filter(original, scaled);
    return scaled;
}
```

But the quality of signature image printed on pdf is not at all satisfactory even after attempting 500 DPI.Am I missing something?

Comment: Is the image itself not satisfactory?

Comment: Why are you scaling the image? Did you try adding the image as is

Comment: You can use a [sharpening kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(image_processing)) to enhance the image

Comment: @iffy6 , image itself was satisfactory.

Comment: @karthick, we cannot add the image as it is.It is too big - we give 320x200 pixel signature pad to the user, as in smaller canvas it will be difficult for user to draw the signature. If you add as it is, image quality is very good.

Comment: @nathancy, I will try sharpening kernel as suggested by you, and report back the outcome on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

So, using the ZetaKey's live-demo, the signature capture returned an acceptable quality PNG image...

**Consider the following things:**

- Can I just use the original, unaltered image?
- If not, can I change the order of my transformations? (DPI -> Scale Vs Scale -> DPI )
- Can I forgo scaling? (often the cause of resolution loss)

I suspect that you are losing image resolution because you're adjusting DPI after you scale the image.

**Effects of Scaling and DPI:**

[Effects of Image Transformations (DPI)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/48825/will-increasing-the-dpi-of-my-image-without-re-sampling-hurt-print-quality)

**Excerpt:** (not directly related, but may give insight into problem)

> Now suppose you want to print your image using a regular offset press, which can print up to 300dpi images. Suppose you try to print it exactly at the original image dimension in inches. The press needs 300 dots for every inch to do a good job. The image you are supplying has only 72 dots for every inch, so the press (or more accurately, the software that prepares the plates for the press) has to make up the missing dots. The result will be blurry or noisy because there will be a lot of "transitional" dots that the software will creatively add to fill the missing gaps.

Comment: E. Millar, I will change the order of transformations & report back the outcome on Monday

Comment: I have tried out all the suggestions including sharpening filter. Not yet sure if they made any positive impact. I have deployed the code, let my QA get back to me what  is their view.

Comment: @SubhenduMahanta if nothing worked, you may want to transition to a vector-based image instead of a pixel-based image.  Vector-images scale without quality loss.  See: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32597/whats-the-difference-between-pixels-and-vectors/